# Show Max and Min Temperature of entire week in C++

Tags: c++

I want to develop a program in C++ which gets the temperature of entire week (7 days) and then shows the max and min temperature and also the day of that temperature. I'm using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //Declare Variables
    /*int Monday;
    int Tuesday;
    int Wednesday;
    int Thursday;;
    int Friday;
    int Saturday;
    int Sunday;*/
    double temp[7];
    
    cout<<"Enter temperature for day 1:"<<endl;
    cin>>temp[0];
    cout<<"Enter temperature for day 2:"<<endl;
    cin>>temp[1];
    cout<<"Enter temperature for day 3:"<<endl;
    cin>>temp[2];
    cout<<"Enter temperature for day 4:"<<endl;
    cin>>temp[3];
    cout<<"Enter temperature for day 5:"<<endl;
    cin>>temp[4];
    cout<<"Enter temperature for day 6:"<<endl;
    cin>>temp[5];
    cout<<"Enter temperature for day 7:"<<endl;
    cin>>temp[6];
    
    //Declaring Max Temperature Variable
    double max = temp[0];
    for (int i = 1;i < 7; i++){
        if(temp[i] > max){
            max = temp[i];
        }
    }
    //Declaring Min Temperature Variable
    double min = temp[0];
    for (int i = 1;i < 7; i++){
        if(temp[i] < min){
            min = temp[i];
        }
    }
    string maxdayname="Unknown Day";
    //Declaring Max Days
    if(temp[0]=max){maxdayname="Monday";};
    if(temp[1]=max){maxdayname="Tuesday";};
    if(temp[2]=max){maxdayname="Wednesday";};
    if(temp[3]=max){maxdayname="Thursday";};
    if(temp[4]=max){maxdayname="Friday";};
    if(temp[5]=max){maxdayname="Saturday";};
    if(temp[6]=max){maxdayname="Sunday";};
    
    string mindayname="Unknown Day";
    //Declaring Min Days
    if(temp[0]=min){mindayname="Monday";};
    if(temp[1]=min){mindayname="Tuesday";};
    if(temp[2]=min){mindayname="Wednesday";};
    if(temp[3]=min){mindayname="Thursday";};
    if(temp[4]=min){mindayname="Friday";};
    if(temp[5]=min){mindayname="Saturday";};
    if(temp[6]=min){mindayname="Sunday";};
    
    cout<<"Maximum temperature is "<< max<<" on "<<maxdayname<<endl;
    cout<<"Minimum temperature is "<< min<<" on "<<mindayname<<endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It's working fine for the max and min values but for Name of day it is keep showing Sunday.

It's giving this output:

```
Enter temperature for day 1:
24.5
Enter temperature for day 2:
27
Enter temperature for day 3:
23.
Enter temperature for day 4:
26.8
Enter temperature for day 5:
30.1
Enter temperature for day 6:
28.1
Enter temperature for day 7:
27.3
Maximum temperature is 30.1 on Sunday
Minimum temperature is 23 on Sunday

--------------------------------
```

Can any one have solution or fix to this?

Comment: This is likely a typo. You need `==` to compare. And also `else if` instead of a chain of `if`. And maybe a loop or a function is more compact than all those code together.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. It was just my typo.

Comment: Homework: look at `std::begin`, `std::end`, `std::minmax_element`. Create an array for the days of the week. A professional programmer could bang out the calculation and output in a couple of statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use == to compare instead of single = it displays Sunday because it is the last to be assigned

Comment: This question is merely a typo. An answer isn't necessarily needed, as declared in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Comment: Yes, it worked by using == instead of =
Thanks

Comment: Didn't reloaded the page